# Cant get JSON data to log in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsonp

I am trying to get this JSON data to appear in the console. When you click on a state, it should log the data into the console. Does anyone know why this won't show? If you go into the network tab you can clearly see it is working and the data is valid. My goal is to be able to see the data I am working with in the console so that I can append it to the appropriate state. I tried a few different things with no success. Hoping someone can help thanks.

```js
$("#mapWhereToBuy").usmap({ 
 click: function(event, data) {  
    var description = '';
    switch(data.name){
    case 'AL': 
     description = 'Alabama';
     break;
    case 'AK':
     description = 'Alaska';
     break;
    case 'AZ':
     description = 'Arizona';
     break;
    case 'AR':
     description = 'Arkansas';  
     break;
    case 'CA':
     description = 'California';
     break;
    case 'CO':
     description = 'Colorado';
     break;
    case 'CT':
     description = 'Connecticut';
     break;     
    case 'DC': 
     description = 'District of Columbia';
     break;
    case 'DE':
     description = 'Delaware';
     break;
    case 'FL':
     description = 'Florida';
     break;
    case 'GA': 
     description = 'Georgia';
     break;
    case 'HI':
     description = 'Hawaii';
     break; 
    case 'ID':
     description = 'Idaho';
     break; 
    case 'IL':
     description = 'Illinois';
     break; 
    case 'IN':
     description = 'Indiana';
     break; 
    case 'IA':
     description = 'Iowa';
     break;
    case 'KS':
     description = 'Kansas';
     break;
    case 'KY':
     description = 'Kentucky';
     break;
    case 'LA':
     description = 'Louisiana';
     break;
    case 'ME':
     description = 'Maine';
     break;
    case 'MD':
     description = 'Maryland';
     break;
    case 'MA':
     description = 'Massachusetts';
     break;
    case 'MI':
     description = 'Michigan';
     break;
    case 'MN':
     description = 'Minnesota';
     break;
    case 'MS':
     description = 'Mississippi';
     break;
    case 'MO':
     description = 'Missouri';
     break;
    case 'MT':
     description = 'Montana';
     break;
    case 'NE':
     description = 'Nebraska';
     break;
    case 'NV':
     description = 'Nevada';
     break;
    case 'NH':
     description = 'New Hampshire';
     break;
    case 'NJ':
     description = 'New Jersey'; 
     break;
    case 'NM':
     description = 'New Mexico'; 
     break;
    case 'NY':
     description = 'New York';
     break;
    case 'NC':
     description = 'North Carolina';
     break;
    case 'ND':
     description = 'North Dakota';
     break;
    case 'OH':
     description = 'Ohio';
     break;
    case 'OK':
     description = 'Oklahoma';
     break;
    case 'OR':
     description = 'Oregon';
     break;
    case 'PA':
     description = 'Pennsylvania';
     break;
    case 'RI':
     description = 'Rhode Island';
     break;
    case 'SC':
     description = 'South Carolina';
     break;
    case 'SD':
     description = 'South Dakota';
     break;     
    case 'TN':  
     description = 'Tennessee';
     break; 
    case 'TX':        
     description = 'Texas';     
     break;
    case 'UT':
     description = 'Utah';   
     break;
    case 'VT':
     description = 'Vermont';
     break;
    case 'VA':
     description = 'Virginia';
     break;   
    case 'WA':
     description = 'Washington';
     break;
    case 'WV': 
     description = 'West Virginia';
     break;  
    case 'WI':
     description = 'Wisconsin';
     break;  
    case 'WY':    
     description = 'Wyoming'; 
     break;    
    }   
  
    $('#clicked-state').text(description); 
    
       
    function logResults(stateData){
        console.log(stateData);        
    } 
    
    $.ajax({     
   url: 'url here' + data.name,
      dataType: "jsonp",
   cache: true, 
      jsonpCallback: "logResults",
   success: function(json){     
      stateData = JSON.stringify(json);
   } 
    });    
          
 }             
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/js/libs/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/js/libs/jquery.usmap.js"></script>

<div id="mapWhereToBuy"></div>
```

Comment: You should use an object literal as a map instead of a giant `switch`.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what `jsonpCallback` means.  You should call the function.

Comment: i just tried that and it says undefined